# Import only specific rows from hsqldb backup

Tags: java, backup, hsqldb

I'm trying to create a function in my `java` application, where the user could select a prior made backup but only import table-rows that aren't in the current database instance. With a `MySql` database I could dump my tables, rename them inside the `.sql` to create temporary tables when imported again, and then simply cross query all rows not in the DB. Any idea how I could acomplish something similar in `hsqldb` from within my `java` application?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. open the backup database
2. create a text table that is a copy of the main table, e.g. `CREATE TEXT TABLE yourtable_copy AS (SELECT * FROM yourtable)`
3. set a file for the table `SET TABLE yourtable_copy SOURCE 'filepath'`
4. copy the data to the new table
5. set the source off with `SET TABLE yourtable_copy SOURCE OFF`
6. shutdown the backup database
7. open the main database
8. now do the same text table creation and source setting with the main database but do not copy the data, as the backup data is already there and will be opend
9. do your updates then turn the text source off in the main database

reference http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/texttables-chapt.html